# Search and assign within one function

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, powershell-2.0

I have two functions, one searches for available LineUri from the CSV file and one assigns the LineUri to the user after checking its availability in the system.

```
$path          = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$phoneDataPath = $path + "\PhoneData.csv"
$log           = $path + "\UserCreationLog.log"

# criteria
$currentStatus    = "Spare"
$userBusinessUnit = "Sales"
$userLocation     = "SA"
$sam              = "srijana.pantha"
$sipDomain        = "test.com.au"
$RegistrarPool    = "s4b-fe01.test.com.au"

$csv = Import-Csv $phoneDataPath -Delimiter ","

function Find-URI {
    $firstAvailableSpare = $csv | Where-Object {
        $_.Status -eq $currentStatus -and
        $_.BusinessUnit -eq $userBusinessUnit -and
        $_.Location -eq $userLocation
    } | Select-Object -Property LineUri -First 1

    Assigned-URI
}
```

Once the above functions finds the LineUri that matches the search query, it then calls the `Assigned-URI` function, which assigns this URI to the user:

```
function Assigned-URI {
    $uriExistence = Get-CsUser | where {
        $_.LineURI -eq $firstAvailableSpare.LineUri -or
        $_.PrivateLine -eq $firstAvailableSpare.LineUri
    }

    if ($uriExistence.LineURI -eq $firstAvailableSpare.LineUri) {
        Write-Host "Already Used"
        foreach ($row in $csv) {
            if ($row.LineUri -eq $firstAvailableSpare.LineUri) {
                $row.Status = "Used"
            }
        }

        $csv | Export-Csv -Path $phoneDataPath -NoTypeInformation
        Find-URI
    } else {
        #Code which assign Line-URI to user
    }
}
```

The `Assigned-Uri` function, first checks the system if that URI is already been assigned to another user before assigning to the new user.

If this is already been assigned to another user, it updates the CSV stating that this URI is already been used and then calls the `Find-URI` Function to find another one.

Rather than having two function, I wanted to accomplish this with one function. Is this possible with some loop functions.

My CSV look like this.

```
Name,SIP,LineUri,Status,BusinessUnit,Location
Test 1,,tel:+61396176100;ext=6100,Spare,Sales,VIC
Test 2,,tel:+61396176101;ext=6101,Spare,Sales,VIC
Test 2,,tel:+61396176102;ext=6102,Spare,Warehouse,NSW
Test 2,,tel:+61396176103;ext=6103,Spare,Sales,SA
Test 2,,tel:+61396176104;ext=6104,Used,Warehouse,WA
Test 2,,tel:+61396176105;ext=6105,Spare,Support,VIC
```

Comment: Any Reason this questions has been down voted..

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Your code works fine with two functions and is easily understandable, why do you want to change it?

Comment: I would stick with 2 functions, but move the verification routine whether or not a URI is already used to the `Find-URI` function, so that that function returns a URI that is actually available instead of one that is maybe available. Then call the second function with that value as an argument instead of having both functions calling each other.